# Actual expectations of a RSpec routing spec is always different from what I specify as expections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have this spec:

```
RSpec.describe 'Routing (i18n)' do
  describe 'Features' do
    it 'has its routes translated' do
      expect(get: '/de/features/automatischer-notruf-ecall')
        .to route_to(controller: 'features', action: 'ecall')
    end
  end
end
```

Which gives me:

```
 The recognized options 
 <{"locale"=>"de", "controller"=>"features", "action"=>"ecall"}> 
 did not match 
 <{"controller"=>"features", "action"=>"ecall"}>, difference:.
```

Ok, no problemo, I thought, I'll just add the locale to the expectations hash:

```
expect(get: '/de/features/automatischer-notruf-ecall')
      .to route_to(locale: 'de', controller: 'features', action: 'ecall')
```

Yes, green:

```
1 example, 0 failures
```

Now the same for the english route:

```
expect(get: '/de/features/automatischer-notruf-ecall')
  .to route_to(locale: 'de', controller: 'features', action: 'ecall')
expect(get: '/en/features/automatic-emergency-call')
  .to route_to(locale: 'en', controller: 'features', action: 'ecall')
```

Gives me this (and the sudden urge to listen to norwegian black metal):

```
The recognized options 
<{"path"=>"features/automatic-emergency-call", "locale"=>"en", "controller"=>"features", "action"=>"ecall"}> 
did not match 
<{"locale"=>"en", "controller"=>"features", "action"=>"ecall"}>, difference:.
```

Why is the exact same expectations hash in the spec (`(locale: 'en', controller: 'features', action: 'ecall')`) suddenly expecting a `path`?

It seems that I can never match the expectations cause the way the hash is interpreted keeps changing to something different from what I have.

So my question is: 
**Does RSpec hate me (personally)?**

Or am I missing something, not being able to see what the problem is?

EDIT:

This is how I get to green:

```
describe 'Features' do
  it 'has its routes translated' do
    expect(get: '/de/features/automatischer-notruf-ecall')
      .to route_to(locale: 'de', controller: 'features', action: 'ecall')
    expect(get: '/en/features/automatic-emergency-call')
      .to route_to(path: 'features/automatic-emergency-call', locale: 'en', controller: 'features', action: 'ecall')
  end
end
```

Which doesn't make sense, does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't make much sense to me. I cannot see Rails doing some crazy (unpredictible) things to you ( ;) ) and your application. Neither does RSpec.

I fear you have some conflicting route defined which does define this `path` variable. Probably also some redirect.

You may want to post your routes file. Glad to have a look at it.

Comment: Won't be necessary. There was a redirect outside of the scope of the translated routes (`get "/en/*path", to: redirect("/de/%{path}")`) which perfectly explains everything. Glad to know Rails and RSpec don't hate me.